# create extension not working in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to install an extension `PostGIS` for `PostgreSQL` so I can use a geographical database.

Here are what I have done:

- I have created a database named `city` and connected to it.
- I have followed [this guide](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS24UbuntuPGSQL10Apt), and typed the following commands that I believe are used to install `postgis`

(from my shell history...)

```
sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-2.4
sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-scripts
sudo apt install postgresql-10-pgrouting
sudo apt install postgis
```

Then I tried to create extension in the database `city`, but got the following error:

```
postgres@yuqiong-G7-7588:~$ psql
psql (11.1 (Ubuntu 11.1-1.pgdg16.04+1), server 9.5.14)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c city
psql (11.1 (Ubuntu 11.1-1.pgdg16.04+1), server 9.5.14)
You are now connected to database "city" as user "postgres".
city=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

As a result, I suspect the `postgis` extension is not installed successfully because I also got this error when trying to check its version:

```
city=# select postgis_version();
ERROR:  function postgis_version() does not exist
LINE 1: select postgis_version();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What am I missing? It would be great if you could kindly points out holes in my understanding. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a version mismatch? "`... install postgresql-10-postgis-2.4 ... `", "`... server 9.5.14 ...`" and "`... file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control" ...`" -- 10 vs 9.5...

Comment: @stickybit thanks, that's what I considered too. I actually searched how to upgrade my server to 11 and did not found it. I then installed postgresql 11, but that does not automatically renew the city database's server.

Comment: You may also want to try to downgrade PostGIS.

Comment: You forgot to provide your OS, but judging from `apt` I assume a debian derivative. Run **`pg_lsclusters`** from the shell to see which Postgres db clusters are installed.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

psql (11.1 (Ubuntu 11.1-1.pgdg16.04+1), **server 9.5.14**)

You are connected to the wrong server, if you have several different postgres servers running you can try connecting to another port, like 5433 or 5434

it looks like you have at least three versions of postgresql installed: 9.5.14, 10.* and 11.1, you have postgis installed for version 10 so that means you need to connect to the postgresql version 10 server in order to create the extension.

Try running:

```
psql -p 5433
```

and see if that connects to the correct postgresql server

Then you need to create the city database if it doesn't exist and then connect to it. Then you should be able to create the extension

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I check which servers are running and connect to a specific one? Currently I just type `psql` and it seems to connect to the 9.5.14 server automatically.

Comment: try psql -p /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433

Comment: Thanks so much. I saw the editing. It's working now!

Comment: Great! :) It can be confusing when you have several postgres running and different databases in them. I think the easiest way to fix it is to uninstall all of them and then install only the version you want. Then you shouldn't have to specify the port anymore. Default port is 5432

Comment: I see. For now I'm worried if I do anything the tool chain will somehow break again and this 5433 port is working for my purpose now, although surely waste a lot of disk space. In the future if I ever need to deal with SQL databases again I'll keep your advice in mind :) Thanks!

Comment: removing the ones you don't use (9 and 11) should be safe, then when only 10 is installed you can change the port in /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf to 5432 leaving them is fine to. you could at least stop the other ones from running so they don't waste your ram: "sudo systemctl stop  postgresql@9.5" and then "sudo systemctl disable  postgresql@9.5" to make sure it doesn't start next boot, and same for 11. "enable" and "start" does what you expect

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just removed version 9 and 11 and nothing went wrong!